# How to end close a macro when the target value is not found in a search

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is finding and targeting the entirety of a column if it matches a specific header(in this case the header is in the second row and it is later being used for find and replace arrays). When the exact text for the search is found the macro works perfectly, however when the macro cannot find the specific string in row two, the macro continues to run and damages data when I want it to simply end the macro and display a message.

I have searched across this site for an answer but nothing that I have found has been helpful(that I understand). I have input message boxes at several points in the string search and tried to get it to return an error message when the string isn't found but that is really the extent of my testing. I have very limited VBA skills and this was written by someone else at my company who is no longer here to question about it. I am a novice at VBA and stack overflow so if there is any additional information or methodology that I need to know please let me know.

```
 Range("A2").Select
  numRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRgUni As Range
Dim xFirstAddress As String
Dim xStr As String

    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = "BusinessPhone"
    Set xRg = Range("A2:CD2").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then

        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = Range("A2:CD2").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                 MsgBox " The " & xStr & " column hasn't been found."
                 Set xRgUni = xRg

            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If
    xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select
```

The expected result is that the macro will either find the string, in this case named businessphone and process it with the rest of the code (which is working as intended). If the strings exact text isn't found, I want it to end the macro and display a message box stating that the column in question hasn't been found.

Comment: `If Xrg is Nothing Then` means the string hasn't been found.

Comment: That is what I thought too. But if I run this with nothing named BusinessPhone in column 2 then it doesnt display the messagebox that I had input. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PJS If it is not found you never get to the inner if.

Comment: Ah I totally missed you already had that. Yes you'll never get to the inner if.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can use

```
Exit Sub
```

to immediately leave a procedure, and

```
End
```

to immediately quit the entire macro, although the latter can be dangerous.